# i can't insert a separator or a notebook in a tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo, separator

i'm having some trouble inserting a separator or a notebook in a tree view. is it even possible ?

The items are usually listed in the tree by the same specifics (name, adress, telphone number...). In my cas, i have two kninds of records (Personne morale and Personne Physique). The frist type should be listed by (nom, prénom, adresse), the second kind should be listed by (raison sociale, siège social,...).

Simply because,the user is given the choice to save the item either as (personne morale) or as personne physique), by hiding the fields related to the other type, so the user only fills the fields related to the type he chose.

```
    <div class="oe_center">                         
                        <sheet>
                            <h2>Demandeur:</h2>
                            <group>
                                <field name="state"/>
                            </group>
                            <group  attrs="{'invisible':[('state', '!=', 'p')],'required':[('state','!=','p')]}" col="4">                       
                                <field name="nom" />
                                <field name="prenom" />
                                <field name="cin" />
                                <field name="adresse" />
                                <!--<field name="dossier" />-->
                            </group>
                            <group attrs="{'invisible':[('state', '!=', 'm')],'required':[('state','!=','m')]}" col="4" >
                                <field name="raison_social" />
                                <field name="num_reg_comm" />
                                <field name="forme_social" />                                   
                                <field name="fax" />        
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="siege_social" attrs="{'invisible':[('state', '!=', 'm')]}" />
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="dossier" />
                                <field name="tel" /> <!-- je viens de l'ajouter -->                     
                                <field name="email" />
                            </group>
```

here is the class i'm talking about :

```
         class demandeur(osv.osv):
_name = 'sayoo.demandeur'
_rec_name = 'nom'

_columns = {
        'state': fields.selection((('p','Personne Physique'), ('m','Personne Morale')),'Statut', required= True),
        'nom': fields.char('Nom', size=100, required=False),
        'prenom': fields.char('Prenom', size=100, required=False),
        'cin': fields.char('Cin', size=100, required=False),
        'raison_social':fields.char('Raison Sociale', size=100, required=False),
        'siege_social':fields.char('Siège Social', size=100, required=False),
        'forme_social':fields.char('Forme Juridique', size=100, required=False),
        'num_reg_comm':fields.char('N° du Registre de Commerce', size=100, required=False),
        #'dossier': fields.many2one('sayoo.dossier', 'dossier'),
        'dossier': fields.one2many('sayoo.dossier','id_dossier','demande d\'autorisation' ),
        'adresse': fields.char('Adresse', size=100, required=False), #'date_naissance': fields.date('Date de naissance'),
        'description': fields.text('Description'),
        'tel': fields.char('Numéro de Téléphone', size=20),
        'fax': fields.char('Numéro de Fax', size=20),
        'email': fields.char('Adresse Electronqiue', size=20),
                }
```

demandeur()

and here is what i tried with the xml, but didn't work

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="Demandeur_tree_view"><!-- d en D -->
        <field name="name">sayoo.demandeur.tree</field>
        <field name="model">sayoo.demandeur</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Demandeur Details"><!-- d en D -->
                <notebook>
                    <page string "Personne Physique">                       
                        <field name="nom" />
                        <field name="prenom" />
                        <field name="cin" /> <!-- je vient de l ajouter pour afficher la CIN dans la vue liste du demandeur -->
                        <field name="adresse" />
                    </page>
                    <page string "Personne Morale">
                        <field name="raison_social" />
                        <field name="siege_social" />
                        <field name="forme_social" />
                        <field name="num_reg_comm" />   
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of view: `tree` and `form`.  The tree view is very simple, and does not handle `notebook`s, `page`s, `group`s. etc.  It also does not handle having different fields/columns showing per record -- in other words, you could list all eight fields, and have only the four correct fields show the data, but all eight columns would always show.

What you probably want to do is have two different `tree` views (one for `Physique` and one for `Morale`) and let the user choose which one to view from a menu selection (the menu xml can have a `domain` set so it only shows the correct records).

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you answer. Can you explain more how can i use the "domain"  to show the correct records ?

Comment: if you use actions (ir.actions.act_window) for you menues then just set the field domain like: <field name="domain">[('state','=','p')]</field> and/or <field name="domain">[('state','=','m')]</field>. so you need 2 actions for 2 menus with different domains :-)

Comment: @CZoellner: change your other answer to have this info, and I'll up-vote it!  :)

Answer (score 1):

if you're using actions (`ir.actions.act_window`) for you menues then just set the field domain like:

```
<field name="domain">[('state','=','p')]</field>
```

and/or

```
<field name="domain">[('state','=','m')]</field>
```

so you need 2 actions for 2 menus with different domains :-)

Comment: The OP did not say he is using OpenERP v7, in which case adding the `version` tag will not help.  The code will also not hide the unneeded fields.

Comment: hm, my bad. i'm too used to use version 7 :/

Comment: Hey, i'm using V7.   i tried creating two sub-menus (personne morale and personne physique), and i gave each one of them a tree view. but the problem is still there. i can still see that teh record exist even if it deosn't show any of the information

Answer (score 0):

You put as a form view, not in a tree view

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="Demandeur_form_view"><!-- d en D -->
        <field name="name">sayoo.demandeur.form</field>
        <field name="model">sayoo.demandeur</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Demandeur Details" version="7.0"><!-- d en D -->
                <notebook>
                    <page string "Personne Physique">                       
                        <field name="nom" />
                        <field name="prenom" />
                        <field name="cin" /> <!-- je vient de l ajouter pour afficher la CIN dans la vue liste du demandeur -->
                        <field name="adresse" />
                    </page>
                    <page string "Personne Morale">
                        <field name="raison_social" />
                        <field name="siege_social" />
                        <field name="forme_social" />
                        <field name="num_reg_comm" />   
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

check this i will work.